# Solidity public variable getter call doesn't return

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I have deployed a very basic solidity contract (`pragma solidity^0.4.0`) to Rinkeby. When I call the getters on my state variables, nothing is returned and I do not understand why. To compile the contract I'm using `"solc": "^0.4.25"`

Using Remix to test, the call to the getter works locally without issue. However, the call doesn't work on my contract on Rinkeby.

Here is my solidity code...

```
pragma solidity^0.4.0;

contract Contest {
    address public manager;
    uint public submissionCost;
    uint8 public votesPerSubmission;

    constructor (uint _submissionCost, uint8 _votesPerSubmission) public {
        manager = msg.sender;
        submissionCost = _submissionCost;
        votesPerSubmission = _votesPerSubmission;
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager, "Not authorized.");
        _;
    }

    function adjustSubmissionCost(uint32 newCost) public restricted {
        submissionCost = newCost;
    }

    function adjustVotesPerSubmission(uint8 newVotes) public restricted {
        votesPerSubmission = newVotes;
    }
}
```

The address of the deployed contract on Rinkeby is

```
0xacBd19113e0D8122E18DF48A320b635fB5D7Cdd0
```

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xacbd19113e0d8122e18df48a320b635fb5d7cdd0

When calling any of the public variables from Remix, I expect a return value, however I only receive the message `call to Contest.manager` in the Remix console and nothing more.

I get the same behavior in my web3 dapp, with zero return when I try...

`await Contest.methods.manager().call()`

Comment: Did you connect Remix to a node on Rinkeby?

Comment: yes i did, through metamask and the injected web3 environment

Comment: It seems you look at console log in remix , under button which call the method you can see the result . any way in console log by clicking on debug button more details showing